# just a small tip on HTML page refreshing

Tags: html, css

All i would like to know is if there is a html line i could add that when i refresh my html  css webpage in browser it scrolls to the very top ? Is this possible?

I have looked online but cannot describe in a short way what i really want, so therefor haven't yet found a solution.

So all i would like is when i refresh my page in browser it scrolls to the very top then reloads the page.

I havent posted my CSS or html code as i do not feel this would be nessesary for this sort of question as i believe it is just a  simple line of HTML that i dont know,

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think you need to provide context for why you need this to happen. If a user hits an anchor that takes them to a point in the page, then if the user refreshed the page it should stay there because that is the correct behaviour.

Comment: can i change this so it goes back to the top?

Comment: I don't think you can do this, normal browser behavior is to refresh the page.

Comment: Using jquery you can make it so the thing scrolls to a certain point without actually adding the anchor to the URL, but I don't use jquery (I have only seen other people use it) and it comes with its own problems.

Comment: The short answer is no, changing the default behaviour is a bad user experience. With context somebody may be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
document.documentElement.onscroll = document.body.onscroll = function() {
   this.scrollTop = 0;
   this.onscroll = null;
}
```

or else you need to go with jQuery:

```
 $(function() {
     $('body').scrollTop(0);
 });
```

I think there are no other option.

Comment: Thanks, is this HTML or css, What document should i past it in the top of ?

Comment: No this is Javascript and 2nd part is jquery . Please read JS then possibly you'll be able to understand this.

Comment: Sure, you can set the vertical axis to zero but without good reason you will break the page. Ask yourself why this needs to happen before breaking correct behaviour.

Comment: Agreed , but do you have any other solution? I know it will break the page but then the question demanded for such an answer.

Comment: The only reason i want to make the page refresh and go to the top is because i have a jquery fixed bar with anchors on it that follows the page, when i refresh the page when scrolled down the bar stays in that position and doesnt go back to the top

Comment: My point exactly, you need to fix the sticky bar so it attaches at any point in the page on load. Not hack the page to fix the bug.

Comment: You could edit your original question and get the right solution.